# Why doesn't Eclipse recognize my Eclipse projects?

Tags: java, eclipse

I tried to rename my top level folder which contains multiple java projects. I also wanted to create a new workspace to point everything to the right location. My current workspace has all the right projects in it, but when I go to import the copied projects into my new workspace, they don't show up. I checked each projects .classpath and .project files and they seem to be the same. I thought as long as they have a .classpath and .project eclipse should recognize them and be able to import them but they don't show up. I looked in the workspace files but don't see anything there that seems of value. What other files do my projects need to be picked up by Eclipse? I'm not even sure how I got them into my current workspace to begin with.

Comment: Describe import procedure

Comment: Hoho, my friend, you are a genius. As soon as I started thinking about it I realized I was trying to import existing android projects instead of existing java projects. That said, not sure why my specific android project wasn't even showing up. I am able to import them all now.

Comment: Check http://nileshk.com/2005/11/03/migrating-myeclipse-to-wtp.html